# Send CSV file via Rest API

Tags: vba, rest, curl, aws-api-gateway

I'm not a developer, but recently have been doing lots of automations at work using VBA, Python and AWS. Recently I started learning and working with API's in AWS.

I've been trying to upload a CSV file through a REST API, but it's just not working as expected.

Basically I have used API Gateway to set up my API that triggers a Lambda Function to upload the file to a S3 bucket.

When I tested my API in Postman, it worked fine, I just had to set Headers as Key: "Content-Type" and Value: "application/csv", then in the Body part I selected "Binary" and browsed my CSV file that I want to upload.

But the problem is when I tried to call my API from my application (or from Postman using the raw text instead of binary), I am sending the following Body (Also tried without double quotes and didn't work either):
`--data-binary "\\file-location\file-name.csv"`.

The API returns a success code, but when I open the file in S3, then content is `"--data-binary "\\file-location\file-name.csv""` instead of the actual file's content that I selected.

This is the code I'm using in my VBA to call the API:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim URL, env, msg, result  As String
Dim objHTTP As Object

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
URL = "https://api-url" 
msg = "--data-binary ""\\file_location\file_name.csv"""

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False

objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/csv" 
objHTTP.send (msg)
result = objHTTP.responseText

'getResponse
ws.Range("s3_api_resp").Value = result

Set objHTTP = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Uploading a file should be done directly to Amazon S3, the reason I say this, is that AWS Lambda has a [limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) of 6MBs as an invocation payload.

There are several ways to upload to S3, here are three ways:

1. SDK
2. CLI
3. Rest API

There is no SDK for VB, but if you are using VB .Net you could use the .Net SDK. An example is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html). Alternatively you could invoke the AWS CLI via VB, that is not so slick (more of a hack) but possible. Details are available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html). Alternatively you can upload a file using the AWS S3 Rest APIs, details available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html).

Files can be uploaded to Amazon S3 without credentials, provided the bucket policy allows open buckets. Examples of bucket policies are available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

If the bucket is locked down (recommended) then you should use temporary credentials to upload to Amazon S3. You can get temporary credentials by either [providing pre-signed URLs for PUT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) or you can grant temporary credentials using a service such as [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/). Amazon Cognito comprises of two parts, User Pools to store credentials and Federated/Identity Pools. You can use Amazon Cognito Identity Pools to generate temporary credentials to Amazon Identity and Access Management using authenticated credentials. Authenticated credentials can be sourced from [Apple, Google, Amazon, Cognito, SAML, and OpenID.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/apple.html) The authenticated credentials are exchanged for IAM credentials. The [IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) credentials are attached to a policy, and that policy should have permissions to upload files.